# Add primary key on upload of source file in django-import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am using `django-import-export` to import data from csv/excel sheets into my models.

This is my code:

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
class ClientResource(resources.ModelResource):
class Meta:
    model = Client


@admin.register(Client)
class ClientAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ClientResource
```

On upload however, I get an error that states:

```
File "\venv\lib\site-packages\import_export\instance_loaders.py", line 31, in get_instance
field = self.resource.fields[key]
KeyError: 'id'
```

From what I understand, this is because my excel sheet doesn't carry the `id` field which is the primary key field. Is  there a way that I can make the resource create an id on upload of each instance of `Client`?

Answer (score 3):

create empty column in file. Example:

file.csv

[image: file csv]

and your code:

models.py

```
  class Client(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name
```

and

admin.py

```
  class ClientResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id','name')


  @admin.register(Client)
  class ClientAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
      resource_class = ClientResource
```

this create a new id when load data from file.